Benchmarks for pallet-treasury failing
I'm currently trying to benchmark pallet-treasury for a chain and they seem to be failing. Here's the output logs
2024-12-19 09:30:22 [ 57 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_treasury::payout    
2024-12-19 09:30:22 Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: PayoutError    
2024-12-19 09:30:22 [ 71 % ] Starting benchmark: pallet_treasury::check_status    
2024-12-19 09:30:22 Error executing and verifying runtime benchmark: PayoutError    
The following 2 benchmarks failed:
- pallet_treasury::check_status
- pallet_treasury::payout
Error: Input("2 benchmarks failed")

And the Runtime configuration
parameter_types! {
    pub TreasuryAccount: AccountId = Treasury::account_id();
    pub const SpendPeriod: BlockNumber = DAYS;
    pub const TreasuryPalletId: PalletId = PalletId(*b"py/trsry");
    pub const MaximumReasonLength: u32 = 300;
    pub const MaxApprovals: u32 = 10;
    pub const MaxBalance: Balance = Balance::MAX;
    pub const SpendPayoutPeriod: BlockNumber = 7 * DAYS;
}

impl pallet_treasury::Config for Runtime {
    type Currency = Balances;
    type RejectOrigin = EitherOfDiverse<
        EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionMoreThan<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 2>,
    >;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type SpendPeriod = SpendPeriod;
    type Burn = ();
    type PalletId = TreasuryPalletId;
    type BurnDestination = ();
    type WeightInfo = pallet_treasury::weights::SubstrateWeights<Runtime>;
    type SpendFunds = ();
    type MaxApprovals = MaxApprovals;
    type SpendOrigin = EnsureWithSuccess<
        EitherOfDiverse<
            EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
            pallet_collective::EnsureProportionMoreThan<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 2>,
        >,
        AccountId,
        MaxBalance,
    >;
    type AssetKind = ();
    type Beneficiary = AccountId;
    type BeneficiaryLookup = IdentityLookup<Self::Beneficiary>;
    type Paymaster = PayFromAccount<Balances, TreasuryAccount>;
    type BalanceConverter = UnityAssetBalanceConversion;
    type PayoutPeriod = SpendPayoutPeriod;
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type BenchmarkHelper = ();
}

I don't think I'm doing anything out of the ordinary in the configuration for it to be failing so I'm not really sure what could be the issue here. Seems to have something to do with the Paymaster::pay() call.

A GitHub link would help a lot to locate the error.

The issue was that there needs to be a BenchmarkHelper defined. Fixed by implementing one.
pub struct TreasuryBenchmarkHelper<T>(PhantomData<T>);

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]

impl<T> ArgumentsFactory<(), AccountId> for TreasuryBenchmarkHelper<T>
where
    T: fungible::Mutate<AccountId> + fungible::Inspect<AccountId>,
{
    fn create_asset_kind(_seed: u32) -> () {
        ()
    }
    fn create_beneficiary(seed: [u8; 32]) -> AccountId {
        let account = AccountId::from_entropy(&mut seed.as_slice()).unwrap();
        <T as fungible::Mutate<_>>::mint_into(
            &account,
            <T as fungible::Inspect<_>>::minimum_balance(),
        )
        .unwrap();
        account
    }
}

impl pallet_treasury::Config for Runtime {
    //...
    //...
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type BenchmarkHelper = TreasuryBenchmarkHelper<Balances>;
}

